Back Gesture Minimizes Flutter App Instead of Navigating to Custom Function with GoRouter Flutter
I'm developing a Flutter application (this is my first flutter project - I'm a beginner) where users can create and manage notes. In the CreateNote screen, I want to override the back gesture so that it saves the note and navigates back to the home screen instead of minimizing the app.
However, the back gesture currently minimizes the app. I have tried using a PopScope, but it didn't work as expected. Here is the relevant part of my code:
ps: back gesture minimize the app instead of going back... here's my git hub link for the project - https://github.com/SonalWelisara/Your-Notes.git
if u can help really appreciate it
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:your_notes/features/model/boxNote.dart';
import 'package:your_notes/features/model/note_model.dart';

class CreateNote extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateNote({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CreateNoteState();
}

class _CreateNoteState extends State<CreateNote> {
  bool isPressed = false;
  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final bodyController = TextEditingController();
  final uuid = const Uuid();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    titleController.dispose();
    bodyController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> onBack(BuildContext context, bool didPop) async {
    if (didPop) {
      return;
    }
    if (titleController.text.isEmpty && bodyController.text.isEmpty) {
      context.go('/home');
      return;
    } else {
      String uniqueKey = uuid.v4();
      await boxNotes.put(
          uniqueKey,
          NoteModel(
              title: titleController.text,
              body: bodyController.text,
              dateTime: DateTime.now(),
              isHearted: isPressed));
      //print(boxNotes.get().toString());
      if (context.mounted) {
        GoRouter.of(context).go('/home');
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
        onBack(context, didPop);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('New Note'),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              onBack(context, false);
            },
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isPressed = !isPressed;
                  });
                },
                icon: Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.favorite,
                    color: Color(0xff555555),
                    size: 27,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.favorite,
                    color: (isPressed)
                        ? const Color(0xff555555)
                        : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
                  ),
                ]),
                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent)
          ],
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                  controller: titleController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Title',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 26,
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 26,
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: null,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                    controller: bodyController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Note',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22,
                        )),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22,
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: null,
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


